# How to set css for random changing div ID or class?

Tags: css, wordpress

I've got a div with class and id that is auto generated with each refresh for the site

like that
`.mnc-row[data-row-id="mnc_row-3259bbbe82bc595"]`

this number "3259bbbe82bc595" is auto generated from the wordpress plugin and there is no option to change the look of this div from the control panel so I need custom css.

can anyone help?

Comment: hi, is that okay if you add a class after the .mnc-row ? then will it work for you

Comment: You can't really use that then. Is there another way to reliably identify the div, e.g. it is always the first one with its parent?

Comment: Also what is the plugin, if it is available online?

Comment: is it one specific box that you want? or do you want all of  the "rows" that the plugin is generated?

Comment: There is always a way to select the element you are trying to get - but since we can't see the html, it is hard for us to help you with the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out the following code

```
#sections div[id^='mnc_row-'] {
    color: red;   
}
```

see the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3q2tg2m/) here
Hope that will work for you

Answer (score 2):

Since the class and id are auto generated, if you have control on where the div is going to be generated, you can wrap it with another div.

Or look for a common pattern. If the div you are targeting has a parent and it is the only child div you can use

```
.parent-class > div {}
```

If there are many children for the parent and if you are sure about the order of the div use the nth-child() Selector

```
.parent-class div:nth-child(2n+1) {}
```

You can also use the first-child and last-child

```
.parent-class div:first-child {}
.parent-class div:last-child {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[att|=val]` selector should do the trick for you. It matches an element where the `att` attribute is exactly `val`, *or* where the `att` attribute begins with `val` followed by a hyphen. So if selecting by the `data-row-id` attribute is okay, and it always starts with `mnc_row-`, the selector below should work.

```
[data-row-id|="mnc_row"] {

}
```

This selector was originally intended for language matching (think: matching `en-US` and `en-GB` with one selector).